# How to plot array with dates of coordinates in python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am new with python.

I have a array with coordinates, and i want to plot in 3d (X,Y,Z) only points.
My array look like Dates=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],.....[xn,yn,zn]]

I tried:

```
plt.plot(Dates[:][0],Dates[:][1]Dates[:][2])

plt.show()
```

but only plot a point.

too:

```
for i in range(len(Dates)):
`plt.plot(Dates[i][0],Dates[i][1]Dates[i][2])`
 plt.show()
```

but plot point sequence and not all points in a figure.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please fix the indentation on the second code snippet. If `plt.show()` is within your `for` loop no wonder why you're in trouble.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html). Last time I checked, the way to go was making an array of ‹x, y› pairs for each value of z.